# Example of a category where some pair of objects lacks a product?

Tags: category-theory

What would an example of a category where some pair of objects lacks a product? Do posets form such an category? I also read the statement that "discrete categories have no products". What does this mean exactly?

I've no formal background in category theory and I'm reading "Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientist".

Comment: The category of fields has no products at all.

Comment: @Randall: That's not true.  It has products of two copies of a prime field of the same characteristic.

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638499/example-of-a-category-without-product

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posets *can* fail to have products. The product of two elements in a poset is their greatest lower bound, and it's possible for elements of a poset to have no greatest lower bound. (On the other hand, there are some posets (e.g. lattices) that do have a greatest lower bound for every pair.)

"Discrete categories have no products" is probably better written "discrete categories do not have products." A category "has products" if every pair (equivalently every nonempty finite set) of objects has a product. The fact that discrete categories do not have products is straightforward from the definition. A product of a pair of different objects needs to have an arrow going into each object. But in discrete categories, any object only has one arrow going into itself.

(Actually, this is not quite right, as Derek points out. The discrete category with one object does have products, since the object's arbitrary product with itself is itself and there are no other different objects for the product to fail to exist with.

**edit 20** And the fun doesn’t end there on this seemingly simple question. The empty category vacuously has all products except a nullary product so whether it “has products” or not depends on if we count nullary products as needing to exist. If so, I’d have to rephrase a couple things above. Having all binary products would not imply having products, and in order for a poset to have products it would have to also have to have a greatest element as well as be a lattice .)

Comment: As a minor nit, the discrete category $\mathbf 1$ *does* have products.

Comment: @DerekElkins Yeah, just thought of that, thank you!

Comment: $x\leq a\times b$ if and only if $x\leq a$ and $x\leq b$-the product in a poset is the greatest lower bound, unless you interpret an arrow $x\to a$ in a poset as saying $x\geq a$!

Comment: @KevinCarlson whoops, thanks!

Comment: The discrete category with zero objects also has products.

Comment: @EricWofsey haha should have probably thought of that when I was reminded about $\mathbf 1.$

Comment: @Eric: not the empty product!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Never answering a category theory question again :-)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for your answer. You mention that it is possible for elements of a poset to have no greatest lower bound - Is this true for Posets over real numbers because we can't define an infimum?

Comment: @PiyushMaheshwari Just to clarify, what do you mean by "Posets over real numbers?" In my answer I am talking about a poset *viewed as* a category by interpreting the relation holding as the presence of an arrow. (There are also categories whose *objects* are posets and whose arrows are order-preserving maps... i am not talking about these.) There are many simple examples of finite posets such that not every pair of elements has a greatest lower bound (in fact discrete categories are a degenerate example of this where no elements are related under the partial order.)

Comment: @PiyushMaheshwari If you're asking about the real numbers viewed as a poset with their usual ordering then actually they do have products in the sense I defined. Any *finite* set of real numbers has a greatest lower bound, the least element (same holds for any totally ordered set). However, not every infinite set of real numbers has an infimum (which is what I think you're getting at) so they don't have all *infinite* products, a stronger condition. On the other hand the interval $[0,1]$ with its usual ordering has all (even infinite) products since any subset has an infimum.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think I understand this much better. Thanks so much for your help!