# Reference request: the terminology "has products" in category theory

Tags: category-theory

I read the accepted answer to the question

> [Example of a category where some pair of objects lacks a product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847251/example-of-a-category-where-some-pair-of-objects-lacks-a-product?noredirect=1&lq=1)

in which the poster gives a definition for a category which "has products", but does so by referencing when a pair of objects in that category "has a product". It seems like this means "the product of the objects is an object in the category", but I would like to see a formal definition in a text if possible, or if not, it would be great if someone could give one here. I would also like to know how you'd prove a pair or tuple of objects has a product. The products live in the product category, and I can't seem to reconcile this conceptually with the products also living in the original category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the core of your confusion is captured in "The products live in the product category". Objects in a product category are *ordered pairs* of objects in the original categories, not *products* of them.

If $a$ and $b$ are objects in a category $C$, the *ordered pair* $(a,b)$ lives in the product category $C\times C$. But the *product* of $a$ and $b$ (if it exists) is another object $p$ in the category $C$, given together with arrows $\pi_1\colon p\to a$ and $\pi_2\colon p\to b$, satisfying the universal property of the product: for any object $c$ in $C$ and arrows $f_1\colon c\to a$ and $f_2\colon c\to b$, there is a unique arrow $g\colon c\to p$ such that $\pi_1\circ g = f_1$ and $\pi_2\circ g = f_2$.

If such an object $p$ exists, we usually denote it by $a\times b$. If a product $a\times b$ exists for every pair of objects $a$ and $b$, we say that $C$ has products. Note that it makes no sense at all to talk about a product of $a$ and $b$ living in some category other than $C$!