# Example of a finite category without inverse or injective limit

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I recently started studying categories theory and i need help to understand the concept of limit. 
Please, tell me an example of a finite category without inverse or injective limit and why. 
Thanks.

Comment: What thoughts have you had about this?

Comment: @ArnaudD. the questions you link to don't give finite categories Also, I think the OP needs to be encouraged  to give us some background and not to treat MSE as a question-answering service.

Comment: @RobArthan I missed the "finite" in the title, my bad (although one of the examples *is* finite). And I totally agree with encouraging users to give background and definitely do not want anyone to treat MSE as a question-answering service; by providing link, I want to encourage users to treat the site *as a list of questions and answers*, and actually *look* before posting. But I should probably be explicit about it...

Comment: So I that spirit, Rodrigo : I suggest you take a(nother) look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and see whether you could make your question better.  (For example, you used the wrong tag on your question. I've corrected it this time, but you could have avoided this by reading the tag-description. Not a big deal, but try to remember it).

Comment: It’s my first time here and i did not know the Rules, sorry.

Comment: I didn't recommend any examples (that was Arnaud).

Comment: @ArnaudD Before i published my question i saw the examples that you recommended but i do not understand. Which one os finite? It’s a chain, i dont see why is finite and why is not exists the limit. I’m new in this world and it’s too strange the language of categories to me.

Comment: The posetal example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638499/examples-of-a-categories-without-products). (I've removed my first comment, since one of the link was not that pertinent, but you (or at least I) can still see it in the "Related" question on the right of the screen if you use a browser).

Comment: @ArnaudD okei, thanks a lot. But i have a question. a and b are not comparables and both of them are lower bounds for c and d. Then, i understand with it that the inverse limit is not unique. Why is it means that the limit cannot exists?

Answer (score 3):

Arnaud D. already gave useful comments, I decided to add a "funny" example.

There exists the only one empty category $\mathbf{0}$ - that is, the category without objects and morphisms. There exists the only one diagram in $\mathbf{0}$ - the empty diagram. This diagram has neither projective, nor injective limit (by the trivial reason: the category $\mathbf{0}$ has no objects!)