# Are all endomorphism identities in a category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am currently studying categories without products. I have found that the category of fields has no products [Examples of a categories without products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638499/examples-of-a-categories-without-products?noredirect=1&lq=1), in the proof an endomorphism appears and while I was trying to understand it, I came up with the question **Are all endomorphisms identities in a category?**

I have no idea how to answer that question. Can someone help me?

Comment: What? No, of course not, and you can find a counterexample in almost any interesting category (finite sets will already work).

Comment: Are you asking whether all endomorphisms **in the category of fields** are identities?

Comment: Something like that @Jochen, I've never taken an algebra course, so I'm trying to undesrtand the basics and while doing so I came up with silly questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not. Even automorphisms need not be identities (an endomorphism that is also an isomorphism is an automorphism).  As we all know, a group is the set of isomorphisms in a groupoid $\mathsf G$ with a single object, endowed with the operation of composition of morphisms: $\text{Aut}_{\mathsf G}(∗)$. Only in a trivial group are all the automorphisms identities.